# Rails send method to namespaced module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic-programming

I am trying to call a method inside a namespaced module. This is what I am trying to do, however I get "undefined method" error. Calling the module method without the send method is working correctly.

```
variable = send "Namespace::#{type.capitalize}Helper.#{type}_method".to_sym, params
```

Thanks for any help.

(Rails 4.1, ruby 2.1.1)

Comment: `variable = "Namespace::#{type.capitalize}Helper".constantize.send( "#{type}_method".to_sym, params)` might work. `send` takes a method name, not the whole `Classname.method` code.

Comment: it's working thanks! please add it as an asnwer so I can mark it as the best :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question was to find a way to call a method inside namespaced module and the answer is in @Satya's comment.

Comment: @sh-ado-w, just a side note, you don't need to convert to sym, `send` accepts strings too

Comment: Ok, thanks for the note, I will edit it in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
variable = "Namespace::#{type.capitalize}Helper".constantize.
  send( "#{type}_method".to_sym, params )
```

(broken into two lines, should still work because of the trailing `.`.)
`send` takes a method name, not the whole `Classname.method` code. You're now doing:

```
Namespace::SomeHelper.send( "sometype_method".to_sym, params)
```